# Graphical SVN manager - Alternative to UberSVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

My company currently relys on tortoise-svn and UberSVN as a web administration / access control platform for our SVN server however UberSVN is no longer maintained and we are looking for alternatives. We have considered moving to a Git based solution, however this would not be suitable for the PCB design work we do as we need to track changes for pcb and schematic files (binary files).

Requirements are:

- Run on linux based server os ie centos, ubuntu, redhat, debian
- Compatible with LDAP authentication
- Free for commercial use

Are there any SVN web access control systems that are still maintained? There are similar questions to this but they all seem to pre-date 2011 and the answers dont apply in 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [SCM-Manager](https://www.scm-manager.org/), if pure Java-app is OK for you ("The SCM-Server is also available as RPM and DEB package")
- [Subversion Edge](https://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion) from CollabNet (costly)

Comment: SCM-Manager is exactly what I was looking for. Installed and tested with LDAP Active Directory integration

Answer (score -1):

Take a closer look at [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) that provides [modern web UI for SVN repos](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/svn-web-interface/). However, you can install and run VisualSVN Server only on Windows OS.

Comment: It says in the question that a linux based OS is required, this is due to the cost of a windows server OS otherwise Visual SVN server would be a contender